# In-place rearrangement of vector in Julia?

Tags: julia

Is it possible to rearrange the values in a vector given a list of indices?

I have two arrays and I want to sort `arr2` based on `arr1` which are both preallocated.

```
indices = zeros(length(arr1))
sortperm!(indices, arr1)
arr2[indices] <-- this returns a copy
```

Comment: `permute!` is your friend. Check the help with `?permute!` on the REPL prompt.

Comment: Nice, that's exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know it existed.

Comment: Want to add that as an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`permute!` is your friend. Check the help with `?permute!` on the REPL prompt.

Specifically,

```
permute!(arr2,indices)
```

should permute in-place `arr2` in the OP. But, the docs suggest on large vectors it might be better to just create a new copy.

Comment: I guess it depends if you are memory or CPU limited whether you would use `permute!(arr2, indices)` vs `arr2[indices]`

Comment: Some CPUs might have special instructions for `arr2[indices]` which makes it better for large vectors (see *scatter* and *gather* ops). Anybody knows if LLVM/Julia would use those?