# In-place modification/reassignment of vector in Julia without getting copies

Tags: vector, julia, in-place

Here's some toy code:

```
type MyType

  x::Int

end

vec = [MyType(1), MyType(2), MyType(3), MyType(4)]

ids = [2, 1, 3, 1]

vec = vec[ids]

julia> vec
4-element Array{MyType,1}:
 MyType(2)
 MyType(1)
 MyType(3)
 MyType(1)
```

That looks fine, except for this behavior:

```
julia> vec[2].x = 60
60

julia> vec
4-element Array{MyType,1}:
 MyType(2) 
 MyType(60)
 MyType(3) 
 MyType(60)
```

I want to be able to rearrange the contents of a vector, with the possibility that I eliminate some values and duplicate others. But when I duplicate values, I don't want this copy behavior. Is there an "elegant" way to do this? Something like this works, but yeesh:

```
vec = [deepcopy(vec[ids[i]]) for i in 1:4]
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36876454/5225341) is a related question.

Comment: Is `vec = deepcopy.(vec[ids])` better? In any case, consider making `MyType` immutable and then `vec[2].x` would not be possible - problem solved (you would have to do `vec[2] = MyType(60)` for the same effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're creating mutable types, and your vector therefore contains *references* to the instantiated data - so when you create a vector based on `ids`, you're creating what amounts to a vector of pointers to the structures. This further means that the elements in the vector with the same `id` are actually pointers to the same object.

There's no good way to do this without ensuring that your references are different. That either means 1) immutable types, which means you can't reassign `x`, or 2) `copy`/`deepcopy`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the context of my project, I want the type to be mutable, exactly because I intend to do something like `vec[2].x = 60` sometime after the rearranging. So `deepcopy` it is.

Comment: You might also consider implementing your own copy method for your struct. Deepcooy will work but might not be as efficient as something you roll yourself.